# LDAP Authenticating user in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm building an authentication script from PHP to LDAP. My problem is that I don't really know how to check for the user if the user isn't my admin.

I don't really understand `ldap_bind` - here I can only login as my admin user, but then I can search for other users in my ou, but I don't know how to check their password.

What I have so far:

```
function login($up, $pw){
    $ldap = ldap_connect("dejan.local") or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

    if ($ldap){
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
        ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        //if I try $up and $pw here, I get an error
        if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, "Admin", "Somepassword")){
            $sr = ldap_search($ldap, "ou=testunit,DC=dejan,DC=local", "samaccountname=$up");
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $sr);

            //so here I've gotten information from the user $up
            //but I would like to check if his password matches and then get his information    
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at some sort of auth scripts from others and they check the information through `ldap_bind`, but I can only connect with my admin user.

Comment: What error do you get? Also, what flavor of LDAP are you accessing, e.g., eDirectory, Active Directory, etc.?

Comment: See [Error 49](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-errno.php#20665) in the list in this comment.

Comment: I'm using AD on Windows Server 2008. I get this error: INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Comment: We use Active Directory at work, but I don't know how comparable it is, since we have multiple domains in our forest, and approximately 600,000+ accounts total. But... When we do our bind, we have to use the domain in the username (e.g., id@domain.example.com). You need to contact your AD administrator to find out what incantation you need to use. Otherwise, you're not providing the correct username/password and/or you're not in the right container to verify that user's credentials.

Comment: I've added @dejan.local which I also use for ldap_connect and it works now. Thank you for your help! Make an answer so that I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: Could you answer one more question please. Now that I can check if the username and password is correct, I wan't to get information from my user. I've used ldap_search for this, but what bothers me is, that I can search the data of all my users with `samaccountname=someuser`. Why is this so?

Comment: Because you're in a directory node, and thus have rights to see that node's data. With Exchange, Outlook and Active Directory, we have a Global Address Book in Outlook. Guess what it is? It's the Active Directory data store (more or less, give or take). It's how Active Directory works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only change you need to make is:

```
if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, "$up@dejan.local", $pw)){
```

Which will make the request local to the specific domain. With Active Directory (which is somewhat different, blame Kerberos), you have to provide a context for login.